# Hausdorff Dimension of a set

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

I am trying to find the Hausdorff dimension of $F=\{1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\ldots\}\cup\{0\}$. This question: [Hausdorff Dimension Calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318007/hausdorff-dimension-calculation) gives some help but I don't think it finishes the answer.

It gives that: there are $k+1$ points, each of which can be covered by an interval of size $\delta=k^{-2}$. So $$\mathcal{H}^{s}(F)\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k+1}{k^{2s}}.$$

I think that this gives $\dim_{\text{H}}(F)=\frac{1}{2}$ since $\frac{k+1}{k^{2s}}=\frac{k}{k^{2s}}+\frac{1}{k^{2s}}$ which is bounded (goes to $1$) for all $s\geq\frac{1}{2}$, but tends to $\infty$ for all $s<\frac{1}{2}$, and tends to $0$ for all $s>\frac{1}{2}$.

However, I'm not sure how to write this out formally. Please help.

Comment: Hausdorff dimension of a countable set is $0$. For a proof, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571937/hausdorff-dimension-of-a-countable-set.

Comment: @student, thank you. I will keep that in mind for future reference. Do you know how to explicitly calculate the dimension for this example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hausdorff Dimension Calculation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318007/hausdorff-dimension-calculation)